# How to format a slideshow

Tags: slideshows

I am trying to create a math presentation and I would like to use mathematica for it (as there are a lot of interactive elements). However I haven't found a good guide on how to format a slide show (there are plenty on how to create one). If you could show me a guide or answer how I can do basic tasks that would be great:

- How do I add new slides?
- How to I add text(titles, subtitles, paragraphs, bullet points)?
- How do I add a title slide?
- How do I add links?
- How do I add pictures?
- How do I change colors(text and so on)?
- How do I add typset equations?

Comment: Have you seen the [Presentations with the Wolfram System](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PresentationsWithTheWolframSystem.html) guide?

Comment: @Edmund Is there a section on formatting? It answers my question on new slides but not my other questions.

Comment: @AzJ, at least from the WTC  template notebook, select Palettes/Slide Show - it contains controls for some, though not all, your points.